# how to do a smouth rotation of a 3D cube and detect the face in front of the screen device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a 3D cube that the user can rotate it by mouse, each face contains an image, i want to detect which face is in the front of the user "or screen of the device" and i want that if the user rotate the cube, it will automatically  oriented " the cube will not be crooked" + automatic appearance of a  text near of the cube.

```js
$(function() {

  var el = document.createElement('div'),
    transformProps = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' '),
    transformProp = support(transformProps),
    transitionDuration = 'transitionDuration WebkitTransitionDuration MozTransitionDuration OTransitionDuration msTransitionDuration'.split(' '),
    transitionDurationProp = support(transitionDuration);

  function support(props) {
    for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (typeof el.style[props[i]] !== "undefined") {
        return props[i];
      }
    }
  }

  var mouse = {
      start: {}
    },
    touch = document.ontouchmove !== undefined,
    viewport = {
      x: -180,
      y: 180,
      el: $('.cube')[0],
      move: function(coords) {
        if (coords) {
          if (typeof coords.x === "number") this.x = coords.x;
          if (typeof coords.y === "number") this.y = coords.y;
        }

        this.el.style[transformProp] = "rotateX(" + this.x + "deg) rotateY(" + this.y + "deg)";
      },
      reset: function() {
        this.move({
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        });
      }
    };

  viewport.duration = function() {
    var d = touch ? 150 : 200;
    viewport.el.style[transitionDurationProp] = d + "ms";
    return d;
  }();

  $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 37: // left
        viewport.move({
          y: viewport.y - 90
        });
        break;

      case 38: // up
        evt.preventDefault();
        viewport.move({
          x: viewport.x + 90
        });
        break;

      case 39: // right
        viewport.move({
          y: viewport.y + 90
        });
        break;

      case 40: // down
        evt.preventDefault();
        viewport.move({
          x: viewport.x - 90
        });
        break;

      case 27: //esc
        viewport.reset();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    };
  }).bind('mousedown touchstart', function(evt) {
    delete mouse.last;
    if ($(evt.target).is('a, iframe')) {
      return true;
    }

    evt.originalEvent.touches ? evt = evt.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
    mouse.start.x = evt.pageX;
    mouse.start.y = evt.pageY;
    $(document).bind('mousemove touchmove', function(event) {
      // Only perform rotation if one touch or mouse (e.g. still scale with pinch and zoom)
      if (!touch || !(event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get touch co-ords
        event.originalEvent.touches ? event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
        $('.viewport').trigger('move-viewport', {
          x: event.pageX,
          y: event.pageY
        });
      }
    });

    $(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
      $(document).unbind('mousemove touchmove');
    });
  });

  $('.viewport').bind('move-viewport', function(evt, movedMouse) {

    // Reduce movement on touch screens
    var movementScaleFactor = touch ? 6 : 1;

    if (!mouse.last) {
      mouse.last = mouse.start;
    } else {
      if (forward(mouse.start.x, mouse.last.x) != forward(mouse.last.x, movedMouse.x)) {
        mouse.start.x = mouse.last.x;
      }
      if (forward(mouse.start.y, mouse.last.y) != forward(mouse.last.y, movedMouse.y)) {
        mouse.start.y = mouse.last.y;
      }
    }

    viewport.move({
      x: viewport.x + parseInt((mouse.start.y - movedMouse.y) / movementScaleFactor),
      y: viewport.y - parseInt((mouse.start.x - movedMouse.x) / movementScaleFactor)
    });

    mouse.last.x = movedMouse.x;
    mouse.last.y = movedMouse.y;

    function forward(v1, v2) {
      return v1 >= v2 ? true : false;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.viewport {
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  transform: scale(0.80, 0.80);
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 50ms linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(20deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 50ms linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(20deg);
  transition: transform 50ms linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(20deg);
}

.cube h2 {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.cube a {
  color: #fff;
}

.cube>div {
  /*  box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #fffdfdc4;*/
  position: absolute;
  height: 370px;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e4f2ff99;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fe7f7f;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.cube>div:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #343a4094;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #b3d7ff;
  background-color: #ffffffd1;
}

.cube>div:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube>div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(200px);
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}

.cube>div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  text-align: center;
}

.cube>div:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube>div:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube>div:nth-child(5) p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.77em;
  margin: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.cube>div:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

object {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

object:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="viewport">
  <section class="cube">
    <div>
      <a class="F3" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">1</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="F1" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">2</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="F2" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">3</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="F4" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">4</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="F5" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">5</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="F6" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <h4 class="titleS titleS1">6</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: why is your Y axis rotation inverted?

Comment: how can i make it straigth

Comment: If you take a look at your own code, you'll see that the element rotates thanks to `rotateX` and `rotateY`

Comment: can't understand you, i want to make te rotation straigth, which canges i should do in my code

Comment: Well, use `-this.y`. But still... the cube acts really weird anyways. `.bind()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()` ... there's too many code to grasp and your question text is not clear.